# Build custom Extjs for panel

Tags: extjs

I'm using an extjs panel that shows information that the user can show or hide. Everything works smoothly. But ext-all.js's size is too big and I've been looking around and saw that there is a possibility to customize it to just use the parts you need. I tried the site's "Build your own" but says the page is not found.

Anyone knows how to reduce the size of the ext-all.js? Or build a custom one?

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own extjs with jsbuilder, which is a software (exists in java and in python.

You'll have to modify the .jsb file, in order to manage dependencies. You can look at how the pkgs files are built.

This is quite difficult, though, to find your way through the dependencies.

The command line looks like (on linux) :

```
java -jar /path/to/JSBuilder2.jar --projectFile $BUILDDIR/ext-lsi.jsb2 --homeDir $DESTDIR
```

I use it often, it's working well now.

But I'm quite sure this will be another adventure for Ext4.

Links

- [Sencha Forum about jsbuilder](http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?8-JS-Builder)
- [Tutorial](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial%3aBuilding_Ext_From_Source)

Answer (score 0):

In your download of ExtJS there is a `pkgs` directory which contains some prebuilt parts.